# Starting a process asking for credentials even though already provided

Tags: c#

I have created a process using the following code:

```
Process process = new Process();
// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = fileToRun;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
process.StartInfo.Domain = "domainName";
process.StartInfo.UserName = "username";
SecureString ss = new SecureString();
"password".ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(ss.AppendChar);
process.StartInfo.Password = ss;
process.Start();
//Check if we need to wait for the process to exit
if (waitForExit)
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

The argument to this process is an http:// location which requires a username and password. Even though I have provided the username and password, I still get a windows prompt for credentials. Is there any thing I need to do so that it does not asks for the credentials?

Comment: I assume you try to launch a browser, and hope that that browser will perform automatic windows authetication against the web site. If so, what's your browser? IE?

Comment: This cannot work, there's no mechanism to get a Windows username+password automatically passed to a web site.  Clearly this would be gross security violation, giving malicious web sites a way to harvest credentials.  Windows also doesn't store passwords, only their hash.  There's no simple solution for your problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Of course it can, if the web site is running in IIS on a server in your domain (intranet) and using Windows Authentication (e.g. with Kerberos).

Comment: Hmm, http://location doesn't exactly sound like an intranet url.  YMMV I guess.